# check if a Name from a table is already listed in a combobox in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to check if a Name from a table is already listed in a combobox, if so do not insert. if not insert. I have tried the following:

```
public void display()
{      
    try
    {
        sc.Open();
        string Query = "select * from Part";
        SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, sc);
        SqlDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string Name = dr.GetString(1);

            if (Name != cbPartners.Text)
            {
                cbPart.Items.Add(Name);//Displaying a list in the Combo Box
            }
            else
            {
                cbPart.Items.Clear();
            }
        }
        sc.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use "select count(*) from Part where Name=@Name" (or whatever is the name of your column), new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDataType.NVarChar) to use the cbPartners.Text value in the query, and cmd.ExecuteScalar to calculate number of matching records. It will be more optimal than what you've already written.

Comment: You tagged winform but in title you have WPF!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ( using linq)

```
if (cbPart.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(f => f.Text).Contains(Name))
       {
             cbPart.Items.Add(Name);//Displaying a list in the Combo Box
       }
           else
             ...
```

Comment: .Text is not recognised?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cbPart.FindStringExact(Name) == -1)
{
    cbPart.Items.Add(Name);
}
```

as side note, you don't need to select all the column, since you only need one column

```
string Query = "select partname from Part";
```

not clear why you removing all the items in `else` case by using `cbPart.Items.Clear();` and that line will remove already existing combobox items when matching item found.

Comment: FindByText is showing up an error: .ItemCollection does not contain a definition for FindByText and no extension...

Comment: ok I am getting the same error, think it is because its winforms?